# index.html.haml Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, z-index

index.html.haml where line #3 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

```
Projects #Index

**= @projects.each do |project|**
= project.name
%br
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because @projects in nil try to add some data after that use that page or you can add condition like if @projects.present? than you can show

Comment: I understand what you want to mean, it's working thank you

Answer (score 1):

This error means you have @projects to be nil

```rb
if @projects.present? 
 # your iterations here 
else 
 # do something else 
end
```